# How to fetch/embed facebook's photos/videos/statuses?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, web-scraping, urlfetch, oembed

I'm trying to embed Facebook's photos, videos or even statuses, but I couldn't fetch anything from Facebook,

**For example**, I'm trying to embed this Photo Post: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=441525965965373&set=a.310879465696691.71407.295546697229968&type=1&theater

### **First (trying oEmbed services):**

- Facebook doesn't support an [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) interface
- Also, I think that Facebook is blocking web-scraping

so some services like [Noembed](http://noembed.com/) (or [Embedly](http://embed.ly/embed)) will work fine to embed content from Twitter, Youtube or even other sites that doesn't support oEmbed interface, but they won't retrieve anything from Facebook, for example, trying to call the service with:

> http://noembed.com/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fphoto.php%3Ffbid%3D441525965965373%26set%3Da.310879465696691.71407.295546697229968%26type%3D1%26theater

will give:

```
{
    url: "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=441525965965373&set=a.310879465696691.71407.295546697229968&type=1&theater",
    error: "no matching providers found"
}
```

### **Second (trying YQL):**

when trying to fetch it using Yahoo's YQL like this:

> [http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url='https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fphoto.php%3Ffbid%3D441525965965373%26set%3Da.310879465696691.71407.295546697229968%26type%3D1%26theater'%20and%20xpath='//meta|//title|//link'%20and%20compat='html5'&format=json](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url=%27https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fphoto.php%3Ffbid%3D441525965965373%26set%3Da.310879465696691.71407.295546697229968%26type%3D1%26theater%27%20and%20xpath=%27//meta|//title|//link%27%20and%20compat=%27html5%27&format=json)

it will give nothing, and you can even try it here in the [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT+%2a+FROM+html+WHERE+url=%27https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=441525965965373&set=a.310879465696691.71407.295546697229968&type=1&theater%27%2band%2bxpath=%27//meta%7C//title%7C//link%27%2band%2bcompat=%27html5%27)

### **Question is:**

How on earth could someone fetch anything from Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally :)**, Facebook now supports a new feature that [enables us to embed "Public Posts"](http://www.theverge.com/2013/8/21/4644942/facebook-now-lets-you-embed-posts-anywhere-on-the-web), So the **short answer** & all we need to know about [Embedded Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/) is in this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

But to embed the answer here ;) , let's do the following:

1- Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag (don't forget replace the `appId` below with your own application ID)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=334259852684024";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

2- Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553"></div>
```